# Spock Framework: problems with spying

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock, spock-spy

I have an issue with using Spy in Spock, it either doesn't work as it should or my understanding is wrong so I'm trying to clarify this.
Consider this code (Java):

```
public class CallingClass {

    public String functionOne() {
        //does stuff
        return "one";
    }

    public String functionTwo() {
        String one = functionOne();
        return "some string " + one;
    }
}
```

Now I want to test the fact that `functionTwo` calls `functionOne` as well as define the returned value from `functionOne` (imagine for instance if `functionOne` is really complicated and I don't want to execute it in my test just want to stub it and set it to return a certain value). For this i write the following test in Groovy (using Spock):

```
class CallingClassTest extends Specification {

    def "check that functionTwo calls functionOne"() {
        def c = Spy(CallingClass)
        c.functionOne() >> "mocked function return"

        when:
        def s = c.functionTwo()

        then:
        1 * c.functionOne()
        s == "some string mocked function return"
    }
}
```

In order to do things like this, Spock is asking me to have the `cglib` library, so my build file (in Gradle) looks something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:latest.release'

    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:latest.release'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:latest.release'
    testCompile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:latest.release'

}
```

Now when I run the test, I expect the `functionOne` not to be called at all, and instead my stubbed out version to be used. Instead, I get this:

```
Condition not satisfied:

s == "some string mocked function return"
| |
| false
| 19 differences (44% similarity)
| some string (-)o(-------)n(-------)e(----)
| some string (m)o(cked fu)n(ction r)e(turn)
some string one

Condition not satisfied:

s == "some string mocked function return"
| |
| false
| 19 differences (44% similarity)
| some string (-)o(-------)n(-------)e(----)
| some string (m)o(cked fu)n(ction r)e(turn)
some string one

    at CallingClassTest.check that functionTwo calls functionOne(CallingClassTest.groovy:17)
```

Even more so, if I debug this and set a breakpoint in `functionOne` it gets called :(

What am I missing? Shouldn't my test use the stubbed `functionOne` provided and just return the string `"mocked function return"`?

Comment: Just in case anyone who is as clueless as myself gets here at some time: in Spock you can't mock private methods (the OP here may know this, of course!): they will just run as normal with a Spy. I found this "limitation" of Spock (it's actually because it does not make testing sense) surprising, in the sense that you *can* call such methods from your Spy (and seem to mock them) in your testing code... It might possibly be nice if Spock could disallow this or flag it as an error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class CallingClassTest extends Specification {

    def "check that functionTwo calls functionOne"() {
        def c = Spy(CallingClass)

        when:
        def s = c.functionTwo()

        then:
        1 * c.functionOne() >> "mocked function return"
        s == "some string mocked function return"
    }
}

public class CallingClass {

    public String functionOne() {
        "one"
    }

    public String functionTwo() {
        String one = functionOne()        
        "some string $one"
    }
}
```

When you both spy/mock and verify this is how return value should be specified.

Comment: This actually works, and it doesn't require the `@Grab` it seems (what's that for btw?) So in Spy-ing, one has to specify the results in the `then` part?

Comment: Do you have a link to where you got that from? I have been unable to find this sort of stuff about Spock so far :(

Comment: Grape (`@Grab`) is a dependency resolver for groovy scripts. You can save the script to lol.groovy and just run it. Exactly, specify result in then block if you *verify* them - checking interactions.

Comment: What matters is that mocking/spying (i.e. describing which invocation is expected) and stubbing (i.e. describing which value to return) for one and the same invocation is done *together* (not separately as in Mockito). Whether to do this beforehand in `setup:` or after the fact in `then:` is up to you. All of this and more is explained in the [Reference Documentation](http://docs.spockframework.org).