# Spock - test fails after interaction testing

Tags: spock

This test works only when condition is tested. When mixed with interaction testing, it fails.

```
class Test extends Specification {

   class Inner {
      public String greet() {
         return "hello"
      }
   }

   def "simple test"() {

      given:
         def inner = Mock(Inner)
         inner.greet() >> { "hi" }
      when:
         def msg = inner.greet()
      then:
         1 * inner.greet() // Below will pass when this line commented out.
         msg == "hi"
   }
}
```

The test will pass when interaction testing is removed.

```
Condition not satisfied:

msg == "hi"
|   |
|   false
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {

    class Inner {
        public String greet() {
            return "hello"
        }
    }

    def "simple test"() {
        given:
            def inner = Mock(Inner)
        when:
            def msg = inner.greet()
        then:
            1 * inner.greet() >> "hi"
            msg == "hi"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it does not make sense to me. Ideally we need to set the mock behavior before checking the outcome of test.

Comment: So you can do it a method's setup block. This is how spock works.

Comment: that's what I did exactly, setting this behavior in the "given" block. I guess given and setup are the same.

Comment: Not exactly, please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875514/spock-framework-problems-with-spying/30875710#30875710

Comment: given is an alias of setup. They are exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk a bit about what's going on. (Or if you don't want to, read the "[Scope of Interactions](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html)" section.)

What's happening is an issue of scoping.  As you may know, you can have multiple sequential when/then pairs; any Mocking done in a then block is actually scoped to only its when block.  What happens if the Mocked method was already defined outside the when/then scoping? The Mock defined in the then block takes precedence.

Congratulations! You've stumbled across the *only* way to overwrite established Mocked values/methods. I spent a long time figuring out how this worked before the new documentation was released.

So we know you're overwriting your mock that defines a value to return. How do we proceed from here?

```
given:
    def inner = Mock(Inner)
    1 * inner.greet() >> message 
expect:
    "hi" = inner.greet()
where:
    message = "hi"
```

Parting thought... I hope you're not testing a value that you set within your test. That's effectively asserting 1 == 1.  If you want to test your actual code while testing behavior I'd suggest using a Spy

```
given:
    def inner = Spy(Inner)
    1 * inner.greet() >> { 
        callRealMethod() // Actual method, read the documentation I linked
    }
expect:
    "hi" = inner.greet()
```